# The C Programming K&R Exercise 1-13

Tags: c

i need your help guys im stuck at K&R Exercise 1-13 . its about functions! I came thru almost all 1 chapter but stuck on Functions. I can't understand how to work with functions. Well I know how to do simple functions but when I came to more complicated one I'm stuck on it! Don't know how to pass the value, K&R example of power function is a bit difficult to understand. But anyway I need your help at Exercise 1 - 13 if its possible for you to complete it so I can read the code and understand how to work with functions.
**Here exercise it self:**
**Write a program to convert its input to lower case,using a function lower(c) witch returns c if c is not a letter, and the lower case value of c if it is a letter**

if you you know some links or anything witch have some useful information about how to work with more difficult  functions (not like passing string to main, but arithmetic one), can you please link them.

Also this is not 2 Edition of K&R

Comment: What was your google query? I suspect your research skills are inadequate. Make sure you're using an up-to-date book; The IT industry changes very quickly and anyone working with prehistoric technology gets left behind.

Comment: @modifiable lvalue I would ask here if i would found any useful information in google . mb my research skills is a bit bad .

Comment: *"...if its possible for you to complete it.."* How about *you* at-least ***try*** to "complete it" and come back, code in-hand, with questions about issues that you experience while doing so.

Comment: @WhozCraig Nice answer . im working on it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have read chapter 1 of K&R , where a simple getchar()/putchar() combination with a while loop. is used to obtain and display characters , am sure you will find this program familiar.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

int ch; 
    while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if((ch>=65)&&(ch<=122))
        {
          if((ch>=97)&&(ch<=122))
              ch=ch-32;
          else if((ch>=65)&&(ch<=90))
          ch=ch+32;
        }
         putchar(ch);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: my K&R is different . i work with Russian version of K&R . 90% of examples in book totally different

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * A function that takes a charachter by value . It checks the ASCII value of the charchter
 * . It manipulates the ASCII values only when the passed charachter is upper case . 
 * For detail of ASCII values see here -> http://www.asciitable.com/
 */
char lower(char ch){

    if(ch >= 65 && ch <=90)
    {    ch=ch+32;
    }
    return ch;


}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char str[50];
    int i,l;
    printf("Enter the string to covert ");
    scanf("%s",str);
    /*
     Get the length of the string that the user inputs 
     */
    l=strlen(str);

    /* 
     * Loop over every characters in the string . Send it to a function called
     * lower . The function takes each character  by value . 
     */
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    str[i]=lower(str[i]);

    /*
     * Print the new string 
     */

    printf("The changes string is %s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AlexGreat . It would be better if you make a first attempt at the code yourself . People here at stackoverflow are more than ready to help people who first help themselves . You can post snippets that you dont understand . However i know that you may be struggling so i posted a small solution . There are various ways to solve the problem . Here is just one . May not be the best . May not be the most optimised one . Hope its gets you started .

Comment: Great ! this what  i was looking for. thank you very much . i actually did almost same thing while tryed to do it my self but with lots of mistakes . Thank you again